# GLSL function used to differentiate between pixels above/below a line

Tags: performance, glsl

I've recently acquired a program which is capable of using a GLSL fragment shader as a plugin. After a short amount of experimentation, I've realized that - for my use-case - I desperately need a function that does the equivalent of the following:

- Takes two 2D points and calculates a line between them
- Returns `1.0` if the current pixel is above (or below, callers choice) the line, and `0.0` otherwise. If the points are horizontally coincident, "above" == "to the left"

For this reason I've created the `slice` function. For my use-case this function has the potential to be called many, many times within a single shader, and should be As Performant As Possible™, but I am no GLSL guru...

My current, working code is below. The function arguments are as follows:

- `aspect`: the current pixel's coordinate
- `p1`, `p2`: the points defining the line
- `top`: whether above or below the line returns `1.0`

```
//Note: !(x ^^ y) == XNOR(x, y)
float slice(vec4 aspect, vec2 p1, vec2 p2, bool top) {
    // degenerate case - shade left or right
    if (p2.x == p1.x) return float(!(top ^^ aspect.x < p1.x));

    // we must center the line over the leftmost point
    vec2 base = p2.x > p1.x ? p1 : p2;

    //calculate the line's slope
    float slope = (p2.y-p1.y) / (p2.x-p1.x);

    //return 1.0 or 0.0 according the rules defined above
    return float(!(top ^^ (aspect.y - base.y)>slope*(aspect.x - base.x)));
}
```

Can this code be made to run faster using only GLSL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try using the dot product for your test. If you take the vector from `p1` to `p2` and form the dot product with the vector from `p1` to `aspect`, it will return the cosine of the angle between them. The cosine of an angle is positive when the angle is between -90° and 90° and it's negative when the angle is in the other 180° of the circle. What this means is that when `aspect` falls on one side of the line it will be positive and on the other it will be negative. So your function could be rewritten as something like this:

```
float slice(vec4 aspect, vec2 p1, vec2 p2, bool top) {
    aspect /= aspect.w;    // <- may be unnecessary if w is guaranteed to be 1.0
    vec2 v1 = aspect.xy - p1;
    vec2 v2 = p2 - p1;
    float cosTheta = dot(v1, v2);
    float result step(0.0, cosTheta);
    return top ? result : 1.0 - result;
}
```

I haven't tested this, but it removes all conditionals and logical operators. If you don't need the divide by `w` then there are no divisions, either. I think this could be faster, but you'll need to profile to be sure.

Note that this assumes that "on the line" can be taken as being on one side or the other. If you need to differentiate that case, I think you'll need either a conditional or some clever non-conditional code to extract that case.

Comment: Good thought! I'll play around with this as I'm off work.

Comment: Also: `aspect` is kind of... special. It normalizes the coordinate of the current pixel, but preserves aspect ratio by normalizing to the smaller side. The final two entries are the extent of the drawing surface. For the center of a 16:9 surface, for example, `aspect = vec4(0.8889, 0.5, 1.7778, 1.0)`

Comment: Well, as long as `p1` and `p2` are in the same space, then I don't think that should matter, since you're not extracting the actual angle, just testing for +/-. The results should be the same.

Comment: Had to alter my method a bit, since this makes point order matter (can't use 'above' and 'below' - need to use 'clockwise' and 'ccw', but it works great! I'll be uploading an answer with my new function in a minute.

Answer (score 1):

My new function:

```
float slice(vec4 aspect, vec2 p1, vec2 p2, bool clockwise) {
    vec2 points = p2 - p1;
    //need -sine from dot product, not cosine; rotate by -90 degrees...
    vec2 pix = aspect.yx - p1.yx;
    pix.x = -pix.x;
    //need sine instead of -sine if counterclockwise
    float inverter = 2.0*float(clockwise) - 1.0;
    return step(0.0, dot(points, inverter*pix));
}
```

The change to "clockwise" works as follows:

- The first point acts like the base of a clock's hand
- The second point acts as the tip
- The function returns `1.0` if the pixel is 180 degrees in the specified direction using the clock's hand, and `0.0` otherwise

I've used the plugin language mentioned above to make an illustration which can be viewed by copying the following code into https://www.interactiveshaderformat.com/sketches/new, replacing the entirety of the code.

```
/*{
    "CREDIT": "by You",
    "DESCRIPTION": "",
    "CATEGORIES": [
        "generator"
    ],
    "INPUTS": [
        {
            "NAME": "point1_x",
            "TYPE": "float"
        },
        {
            "NAME": "point1_y",
            "TYPE": "float"
        },
        {
            "NAME": "point2_x",
            "TYPE": "float"
        },
        {
            "NAME": "point2_y",
            "TYPE": "float"
        },
        {
            "NAME": "clockwise",
            "TYPE": "bool"
        }
    ] }*/

vec4 getAspect() {
    vec4 aspect;
    aspect.z = max(RENDERSIZE.x/RENDERSIZE.y, 1.0);
    aspect.w = max(RENDERSIZE.y/RENDERSIZE.x, 1.0);
    aspect.xy = isf_FragNormCoord.xy * aspect.zw;
    return aspect;
}
float slice(vec4 aspect, vec2 p1, vec2 p2, bool clockwise) {
    vec2 points = p2 - p1;
    vec2 pix = aspect.yx - p1.yx;
    pix.x = -pix.x;
    float inverter = 2.0*float(clockwise) - 1.0;
    return step(0.0, dot(points, inverter*pix));
}

void main() {
    vec4 aspect = getAspect();

    vec2 point1 = vec2(point1_x, point1_y);
    vec2 point2 = vec2(point2_x, point2_y);

    float color = slice(aspect, point1, point2, clockwise);
    if (distance(aspect.xy, point1) < 0.01)
        gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    else if (distance(aspect.xy, point2) < 0.01)
        gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    else gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(color), 1.0);
}
```